# Unable to post multiple selection custom listbox values from register form

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, form-fields-types, registration

I have created a multiple selection list in registeration form so on the registeration.xml i have pasted this code

```
<field name="groupMember"
            type="list"
            description="choose cybertechnos groups"
            filter="username"
            label="Choose Groups"
            multiple ="true"
            >

 <option value ="A">A</option>
                <option value ="B">B</option>
                <option value ="C">C</option>
     </field>
```

I have also defined its variable in the JUser user.php file like below

```
    public $groupMember = null;
```

Now user is able to register fine but the saved value displays only single text "Array" seems like there is nothing except Array coming from the form.

I have var_dump the value on register function of com_users\models\registeration.php

the values display like this

["groupMember"]=> string(5) "Array"

> array(8) { ["groupMember"]=> string(5) "Array" ["name"]=> string(4)
>   "abcd" ["username"]=> string(4) "abcd"..............etc

seems like i am not getting any real array object.

I am very new in joomla , Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it my self , Just need to convert array into string inside the controller class of registration e.g. components/com_users/controllers/registeration.php

inside the function called "register"

```
 if ( is_array( $requestData['groupMember'] )) {
            $requestData['groupMember'] = implode( ',', $requestData['groupMember'] );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `Array` because there are multiple, potential values as you're using the `multiple=""` attribute.

If you use `var_dump($groupMember);`, you'll see the values inside the array.

To display the value, you will need to use a `foreach` loop, like so:

```
foreach ($groupMember as $group)
{
    echo $group . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: I have var_dump the value on register function of com_users\models\registeration.php

the values display like this

["groupMember"]=> string(5) "Array" i need to save the values of the array and i cannot iterate it untill it show the type as Array not the string it self. Seems like the form is sending array but the data displaying array as string not sure what to do